# Performance issue with partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, partial-views

I've got a View with many things, among them is this:

```
@Html.Partial("AddWindow")
@Html.Partial("EditWindow")
```

Each of these partial views contains a [Kendo Window](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/ajax) whose contents are loaded via Ajax.

The Kendo Windows in each partial are opened via a button call but what is actually happening is that they are loaded as soon as the page is accessed. I just want them to load when I click those buttons.

Without those two lines of code, the CSS animations were fluid throughout the page. Now, they break for a second for each Ajax load (I tried to remove one of the partials and only one break is revealed, and no partials means no break at all). The breaks are invisible when the windows are actually opened but when entering the page, the CSS animations break twice, one for each Ajax load. After that, everything fine.

```
function openAdd() {
    $("#addWindow").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
}
```

I was thinking that inside the above function should be something that, not only opens the kendo window, but also loads the partial into the view.

Any help?

Comment: put the code of one of your view in order to modify it for you

Answer (score 1):

here what you can do

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("addWindow")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Width(450)
    .Height(400)
)


<script type="text/javascript">
 function openAdd() {
    var window = $("#addWindow").getKendoWindow();
    window.refresh({
         url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
    });
    window.title('Title');
    window.center().open();
}
</script>
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you, I will try this shortly and get back to you. By the way, there's an extra comma in your code after `'@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'`: remove it

Comment: if you want help about how you will pass the id to the editwindow, go ahead and ask

Comment: No need for that. This doesn't work since it breaks on the refresh line: the window doesn't exist yet, it only exists inside the partial view, which hasn't been loaded initially

Comment: put the window outside the partial view, and it can be accessed by different view ( Add , Edit)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that will work but I wanted to have the window inside a partial view in order to reuse it. This way I'll have to put windows inside every view instead of a simple Partial call. Do you know how?

Comment: then construct the window in the javascript before you try to load it

Comment: question: where are the buttons that will fire the window? inside the partial view or outside?

Comment: The buttons are outside the partial view, of course. The partial view contains the only the kendo window.